# Flutter datepicker change style of disabled day/month (ideally crossed out or color change)

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter v2.10.3. I am building Android + iOS app. I need to allow user to pick date range (with time). Trouble is that some dates are not available, in this case picker shouldn't allow selecting range.
It looks I can't easily use daterange picker, it's fine (however if you see any solutions then please let me know?), 2x datepicker is ok. I am able to exclude some dates, but I cannot change style of inactive day. Is there any easy way how to customize it (disabled day style)? Ideally I'd like to make crossed out day numbers,  but if it's not possible then I need color change/opacity at least. I tried updating theme (builder property in showDatePicker), I can update a lot, but none of properties are working for disabled days.

I tried disabledColor property but id doesn't work

Any ideas appreciated

[image]

Comment: You could look at the source code of DatePicker and see which theme elements it is accessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to modify datepicker source code at `flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/date_picker.dart`

at this part

```
else if (isDisabled) {
      //itemStyle = textTheme.bodyText2?.apply(color: colorScheme.onSurface.withOpacity(0.38));
      itemStyle = textTheme.bodyText2?.apply(color: Color(0xFFF44336));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can change the onSurface color like so

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context)
       .copyWith(colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(onSurface:Colors.white),
datePickerTheme: DatePickerThemeData());
```